# $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^p} \not= 1$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Is the following statement true: $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^p} \not= 1$. This is for any $p \in \mathbb{R}$. I gave an counterexample with $p=-2$ then the integral is $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^-2}=1$ exactly. But I'm bad at math, so I want to make sure is right.

Comment: Hint: $\int_0^1 x^p dx = \frac{1}{p+1}$. Can you find a $p$ such that $\frac{1}{p+1} = 1$?

Comment: @ArunBharadwaj Note OP wants to integrate the *reciprocal* of $x^p$ over $[0,1]$.

Comment: The counter-example is when $p=0.$ Using your example $p=-2,$ the value of $1/(x^p)$ is $x^2$ and the integral is $1/3 \neq 1.$

Comment: Ok, so it's wrong again. See, I am bad at math.

Comment: @coffeemath oops! Thank you for catching that haha (It is too late into the night on this side of the globe).

Comment: @judgeKevin It's okay to feel stuck with problems sometimes; that doesn't mean you are automatically bad at math. Math just takes time; so power to you my friend to keep at it. Like you clearly see; people supposedly here to help you (aka me), slip up too! (like I did in my reply comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Power Rule of Integration states
$$\int x^p\,\text dx=\frac{x^{p+1}}{p+1}+C$$
So,
$$\int_0^1\frac{\text dx}{x^p}=\left[\frac{x^{-p+1}}{-p+1}\right]_0^1$$
$$=\frac{1^{1-p}}{1-p}-0=\frac{1}{1-p}$$
If this is to be one,
$$1-p=1\implies \boxed{p=0}$$
Hence, the statement is false for $p=0$.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Comment: Note the antiderivative is actually $\ln(x)$ in case $p=-1.$ That doesn't affect your answer since you eventually get $p=0.$ [+1 on answer]

Comment: Ok, so it's wrong again. See, I am bad at math.

Comment: @coffeemath: Of course, because the fraction is not defined for $1+p\neq0$. Thanks for reminding!